# Why calling cloned() on Iter with inferred Item type allows it to be passed into this function?

Tags: iterator, rust

I was trying to learn a little bit about Iterator and how it works and I was hoping some of you could explain to me somthing about this code:

```
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<_> = (0..10).map(|_| 2).collect();
    let it = a.iter();
    print(it);
}

fn print<I: Iterator<Item=usize>>(iter: I) {
    for x in iter {
        println!("{}",x);
    }
}
```

I know that the code above is very convoluted, but its the simples code that I ve created from much more complicated version in which it made more sense, just to find the core of the problem and understand it better.

When compiling this code in rustc I have this compile error:

```
src/main.rs:5:5: 5:8 error: type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, _> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == usize`:
 expected &-ptr,
    found usize [E0271]
src/main.rs:5     print(it);
                  ^~~
```

I fixed it by changing let to:

```
let it = a.iter().cloned();
```

or

```
let it = a.iter().map(|&x| x);
```

As far as I understand the error suggest that compiler cannot safely inferr type of the Item that I am trying to pass as argument, but why does calling cloned() or map changes anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `print` function expects an Iterator of `usize`s as an argument, but `it` (in your first version) is an iterator that yields `&usize` values, i.e. references to a `usize`.

`cloned()` essentially maps `Clone::clone` over an iterator, so it transforms an iterator of `&T` into an iterator of `T`, so that fixes the type mismatch in your program.

Your final version (`let it = a.iter().map(|&x| x);`) also converts the iterator from an iterator of `&T` into an iterator of `T`, but this time by dereferencing the elements using pattern matching.

Since `print` doesn't actually need to own the elements of the iterator, you could also fix your problem by changing its type to the following:

```
fn print<'a, I: Iterator<Item=&'a usize>>(iter: I)
```